# Setting up U-Boot for A/B partitioning within Mender

Tags: partitioning, bootloader, u-boot, buildroot, mender

Currently I try to implement A/B partitioning so I can perform system updates with Mender and rollback if necessary.
One problem is, that the device numbers can change randomly and I need to consider this.

```
# lsblk
NAME         MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINTS
mmcblk0      179:0    0  7.3G  0 disk              # This can became mmcblk1
|-mmcblk0p1  179:1    0  250M  0 part /            # rootfsA, rootfsB not implemented yet
`-mmcblk0p2  179:2    0   50M  0 part /mnt         # Data partition, persistent
mmcblk0boot0 179:32   0    4M  1 disk              
mmcblk0boot1 179:64   0    4M  1 disk
```

At the moment I handle this way.

```
set_bootargs=env set bootargs root=PARTUUID=00000000-0${bootpart} rootfstype=ext4 rootwait ${console} rw panic=5
```

After I performed the update (custom script overwrites rootfsB), I need to perform `fw_setenv upgrade_available 1`. Afterwards if boot to rootfsB was successful I will set `fw_setenv upgrade_available 0` and `fw_setenv bootcount 0`.

My `fw_config.cfg` looks like this

```
# U-Boot environment is stored on the data partition
/mnt/uboot.env      0x0000      0x1000
```

What do I need to do in order to load `/mnt/uboot.env` into U-Boot and, write to it from OS and keep this changes so if `bootcount` == `bootlimit` my `altbootcmd` will control which partition to boot?

[uboot.config](https://pastebin.com/HV3UeY3z)

| Component | Specification |
| --- | --- |
| SBC | Radxa Zero v1.51, 2GB RAM, 8GB eMMC, 4 Cores |
| SOC | S905Y2 |
| Processor | ARM Cortex-A53 |
| Architecture | ARMv8-A |
| WiFi/BT | [AP6256](http://files.pine64.org/doc/datasheet/PinebookPro/AP6256%20datasheet_V1.7_12282018.pdf), BCM43456/BCM4345C5, b/g/n/a/ac - BT5.0 |
| OS | Buildroot 2022.11, System V |
| Kernel | Latest CIP SLTS version (5.10.145-cip17) |
| Bootloader | Custom [U-Boot 2021.01](https://github.com/radxa/u-boot/tree/radxa-zero-v2021.01) with vendor FIP |
| Pinout | [Link](https://wiki.radxa.com/Zero/hardware/gpio) |
| Quick Reference Manual | [Link](https://dl.radxa.com/zero/docs/hw/S905Y2%20Quick%20Reference%20Manual%20v0.7.pdf) |

Comment: I've set `BOOTCOUNT_ENV [=y]` so `bootcount` is stored in env.

Comment: Right, `BOOTCOUNT_ENV [=y]` is set so `bootcount` will be counted if `upgrade_available=1`. Furthermore I need to set `bootlimit=5` in my U-Boot env.
I also managed to write U-Boot env from OS when set `CONFIG_ENV_IS_IN_EXT4=y`. The U-Boot env is now stored on my persisten data partition.